# Independent or dependent events for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

From the attached image of a tree diagram, is it possible to obtain $P(A)$? I would like to get hint rather than the answer. I drew the diagram from the below scenario but I am having difficulty determining $P(A)$ and whether or not the events are independent. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMFbm.png)

The event of picking a person with red hair is A.
The event of picking a female is B. 
The probability of picking red hair and female is $.05$ and the probability of picking a female is $0.25$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability of picking a female with red hair? What is the probability of picking a male with red hair? Then add these two probabilities to get $P(A)$.

The events cannot be independent since $P(A|B)\neq P(A|B')$.

Comment: From image, probability of red hair and female is 0.05 and the probability of male is 0.75. For probability of male and red hair don't I need the probability of picking red hair? And how do I calculate for that?

Comment: @user2220115 you calculate it the same way, just using a different branch of the tree: probability of male and red hair is $0.75\times0.067$.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked, here is your **Hint:**

Use the **Law of total probability**  $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B')$